# Nested for each function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and I am stuck on what I feel is a simple task.

I am trying to display the output of a function which works in my first two scenarios but not in the third. What am I do wrong?

Code:

```
let fmCloud =            FileManager.iCloud()
let strPath = fmCloud.bookmarkedPath("Batman")
let InputName = "dddd";


function mainFunction() {
    function subFunction() {
        var sample = "hello world";
         return sample;
    }
     return subFunction;
}
 var test = mainFunction();
 console.log( test() );



 function TestName(InputName) {
     function Subman() {
         var sample = "hello world2";
         return sample;
    }
     return     }
 var test1 = TestName(InputName);
 console.log( test1() );


 function CreateName(InputName) {
fmCloud.listContents(strPath).forEach( function(p_strPath) {
         var sample = "hello world3";
         return sample;
    }
     return p_strPath;
}
 var test2 = CreateName(InputName);
 console.log( test2() );
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Also there is a typo, you are missing a closing parenthesis for the opening parenthesis of `forEach`

Comment: I am trying to find out if each item in a folder is a file.or a folder. I took everything out and just added the sample to make it simple for me.

Comment: Oh and I realised about the parenthesis but that made no difference

Comment: The error I am getting is the is no variable called p_strPath

Comment: that's because you are trying to use it outside the `forEach`

Comment: I thought you could do that if you used 'return' like in my first two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

p_strPath is only usable inside the .forEach function. Since you use it outside the function, the code has no idea what it is. I would return p_strPath instead of sample and debug from there